# Binding additional data values for jQuery UI with ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, model-binding

Having trawled the inter-webs for an answer to this I have come up dry.

My aim with the function below is to be able to populate an autocomplete textbox with values which will contain text visual aids, but backing values. I require these to be bound to a complex object when posted to my MVC controller within a form.

Other than using multitudes of hidden fields, are there any other ways to achieve what I need?

```
 $("#addressString")
                .autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/Send/Send/GetAddressBook',
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: { query: extractLast(request.term), groupName: $('#SelectGroupName').val() },
                            term: extractLast(request.term),
                            success: function (data) {
                                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item.label,
                                        value: item.label,
                                        id: item.id,
                                        type: item.type
                                    };
                                }));
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    search: function () {
                        var term = extractLast(this.value);
                        if (term.length < 1) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        return true;
                    },
                    focus: function () {
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        var terms = split(this.value);
                        terms.pop();
                        terms.push(ui.item.value);
                        terms.push("");
                        this.value = terms.join("; ");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
        });
```

Comment: In the past I have done a custom rendering function for the autocomplete entries and stored the complex object in a hidden field as json.

Comment: @JohnKalberer - Thanks John, I suppose in this instance storing the json hidden field could be bound with some custom model binding magic. I will look into this. I still wonder though - is this the only solution?

Comment: You could use knockout.js for this

Comment: @ShaneKm thanks for your comment - could you provide any sample code on using knockout for this purpose?